# Fitting a skew normal with function selm

Tags: r

I was writing this code to fit a skew-normal to my data. Since I had some crazy value for alpha (alpha=183) I wanted to choose a starting point and see if things goes better. This is my code

```
my.mle=selm(Y2~1,start = list(xi=1, omega=1, alpha=0))
```

but I get this error

```
Error in abs(alpha) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

what's wrong?

Comment: Can't say for sure what's goingon without more info. But it seems the best guess at a starting value will be given by using the mean, skew, and variance of the data and solving for xi, omega, and alpha using the formulae on the [author's site](http://azzalini.stat.unipd.it/SN/Intro/intro.html).

Comment: Specifically, with `s` being the standard deviation of your data, `u` being the mean, and `g` the skew, we can solve for: `omega = s * sqrt(1 + psi)`, `xi = u - s * psi^(.25)`, and `alpha = sqrt(psi * pi / (2 + (2 - pi) * psi))`, where `psi = sqrt(g / (2 * (pi - 3)))`. (algebra mistakes possible)

Answer (score 0):

if you choose alpha=0 your fisher information matrix become singular and so your maximization doesn't work.